# Unit testing - test runner failed to instantiate

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to make a unit test in order to test the login screen of an app using espresso but i keep getting this error. I don't know what else to try and i don't know the source of this error either

This is the code:

```
package com.example.tiditu;

import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso;
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents;
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import kotlin.jvm.JvmField;

import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.replaceText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended;
import static androidx.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Initialize Firebase authentication instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Disable animation for Espresso tests
        Intents.init();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // Sign out the user after the test
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            mAuth.signOut();
        }

        // Release resources and allow the app to proceed with animations
        Intents.release();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccessfulLogin() {
        // Perform login actions
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.username)).perform(replaceText("username@example.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.password)).perform(replaceText("password"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.loginbtn)).perform(click());

        // Verify that the MainUserScreen activity is launched
        intended(hasComponent(MainUserScreen.class.getName()));

        // Verify that the username and password fields are no longer displayed
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.username)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.password)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate test runner class androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner



    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.throwInitializationError(AndroidJUnit4.java:129)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:121)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:82)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.<init>(AndroidJUnit4.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.loadRunner(AndroidJUnit4.java:112)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.RunnerArgs$Builder.<init>(RunnerArgs.java:248)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.createRunnerParams(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.os.StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads(StrictMode.java:30)
    at androidx.test.internal.platform.ServiceLoaderWrapper.loadService(ServiceLoaderWrapper.java:45)
    at androidx.test.internal.platform.ServiceLoaderWrapper.loadSingleServiceOrNull(ServiceLoaderWrapper.java:89)
    at androidx.test.internal.platform.ServiceLoaderWrapper.loadSingleService(ServiceLoaderWrapper.java:72)
    at androidx.test.platform.io.PlatformTestStorageRegistry.<clinit>(PlatformTestStorageRegistry.java:46)
```

I tried different suggestions from stackoverflow like writing JvmField or updating the dependencies but nothing worked